# MPMusicPlayerController pause while in background and resume when app enters foreground

Tags: iphone, background, resume, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have implemented MPMusicPlayerController to play music from library. When app enters background, i pause it and when it comes back to foreground, i want it to resume. It pauses fine but begins from the start. Heres the code...

AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.appMusicPlayer pause];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.appMusicPlayer play];
}
```

MainViewController.m

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
   appdelegate.selectedSongCollection=mediaItemCollection; 
    appdelegate.appMusicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

    [appdelegate.appMusicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection:appdelegate.selectedSongCollection];
    [appdelegate.appMusicPlayer play];
    [btnStop setHidden:NO];
    [btnMusic setHidden:YES];
}

- (void) mediaPickerDidCancel: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker 
{   
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; 
}
```

Any ideas on how to resume it when app enters foreground?

Comment: I would check the seek time of the song you are attempting to play in WillEnterForeground. I assume it's getting reset, so just save it on didEnterBackground and set it in WillEnterForeground

Answer (score 2):

I would look into the track's currentPlaybackTime. MPMusicPlayerController has a currentPlaybackTime property. When the app is going to enter the background, simply save this value (as a property should work just fine), and in WillEnterForeground, use the same property's value to set the currentPlaybackTime when you resume.

Comment: great idea, will try and revert back. What i ended up doing yesterday was using iPodMusicPlayer instead of applicationMusicPlayer and pausing and resuming it in background and foreground methods respectively.

Comment: I've had my hopes that it wouldn't have to come to this, but it's still a viable solution thanks to `NSNotificationCenter`.